# Compute Thrust from RPM and Induced Velocity

Tags: aerodynamics, propeller, quadcopter, thrust

I'm attempting to calculate the difference in thrust in a secondary propeller operating in the wake behind a primary propeller, in the context of a trailing quad-copter following a leading quad-copter in close proximity.

I'm using the model from [Propeller Slipstream Model for Small Unmanned Aerial
Vehicles](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Waqas_Khan15/publication/264773240_Propeller_Slipstream_Model_for_Small_Unmanned_Aerial_Vehicles/links/54c289670cf2911c7a4922cd/Propeller-Slipstream-Model-for-Small-Unmanned-Aerial-Vehicles.pdf) and have so far simply linearly superimposed two of the induced velocity fields on top of one another, as far as I am aware a linear superposition should give a reasonably accurate induced velocity field for now.

I'm wondering if there is a way to calculate the thrust a propeller is creating just from this induced velocity field. I should also note that the thrust the propeller generates is one of the input variables into the model, so I am assuming that I will need to work out how much additional thrust the second propeller requires to give the flow field generated